# git repo ignore a subdirectory

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I created a git repository and add some directories in that repo. When I push to git server, one of the directory is not recognized by the server. Please see below screenshot,

[image]

You can see that the nurse360_ios folder is gray. Whatever I updated on that folder, all are ignored by git.

Below is my .gitignore file:

```
$ cat .gitignore 
Podfile.lock
Pods
#nurse360_ios.xcworkspace
#nurse360_ios.xcodeproj/xcuserdata
```

I don't know why it is ignored by git. And I searched and someone say it may be a submodule. But I didn't create submodule. How can I check the root course for this?

Comment: The screen shot above can't possibly be containing all the files in the root folder of your project - the `.git` directory is missing.

Comment: Is the `nurse360_ios` itself a git repository?  That is, does it contain its own `.git` directory?

Comment: the nurse360_ios doesn't contain .git directory.

Comment: @mzedeler the .git directory is on the repo directory. I can do git command for other directories except "nurse360_ios".

Comment: Are you asking how to figure out who added those to the `.gitignore`? You could use `git blame`. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame

Comment: No I want to add the folder nurse360_ios in my git repo but it got ignored for some reason I want to figure out.